# This sequence $\lfloor \sqrt{2003}\cdot n\rfloor $ contains an infinite number of square numbers

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

> Show that: the sequence $\lfloor \sqrt{2003}\cdot n\rfloor $ contains an infinite number of square numbers.

Maybe consider the Pell equation to solve this problem. But how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume that $\frac{p}{q}$ is a convergent of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{2003}$. We have
$$ \left|\sqrt{2003}-\frac{p}{q}\right|\leq \frac{1}{q^2} $$
hence $n=pq$ (or $n=pq\pm 1$) is a good candidate for $\left\lfloor n\sqrt{2003}\right\rfloor$ to be a square, since
$$ \left| pq\sqrt{2003}-p^2\right|\leq \frac{p}{q}\approx\sqrt{2003}. $$
You just have to show that among the best rational approximations given by the continued fraction of $\sqrt{2003}$, there are some "very best" approximations for which
$$ \left|\sqrt{2003}-\frac{p}{q}\right|\leq \frac{C}{q^2} $$
holds with a very small constant $C$.
 That can be done by explicitly writing the continued fraction of $\sqrt{2003}$
$$\sqrt{2003}=[44;\overline{1,3,12,1,1,6,2,1,2,1,3,6,7,1,\color{red}{43},1,7,6,3,1,2,1,2,6,1,1,12,3,1,\color{red}{88}}]$$
and studying what happens at each step, especially when we meet a large element of such continued fraction.

Comment: Not a waste of your time, this (+1)!

Comment: necessary to be able to solve $x^2 - d y^2 = -2$ or $x^2 - d y^2 = -1.$  I solved $x^2 - 7 y^2 = -3$ and $ \lfloor xy \sqrt 7 \rfloor$ is always one larger than a square.

Comment: in case of interest: I put another CW answer just now, why $x^2 - d y^2 = -k$ does not work for this problem when $k \geq 3.$ Also, I put a question yesterday as to why there seems to be little trouble finding squares anyway. Turns out to be 1916 theorem of Weyl. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937378/when-is-the-floor-of-an-integer-times-the-square-root-of-seven-a-square

Comment: Awesome! I suspected there should be some result for general irrational numbers—great find.

Comment: @WillJagy: I agree we may use Weyl's equidistribution theorem also here, but I think it is quite an overkill, since the continued fraction of $\sqrt{2003}$ *has* large elements (while the same does not happen for $$\sqrt{7}=[2;\overline{1,1,1,4}].$$)

Comment: Jack, I agree, this would not be a contest question or, in consequence, appear on MSE from some student, unless there were a way to do it without quoting a major theorem. Meanwhile, I knew nothing of Weyl's equidistribution until the comments by @mercio at my question yesterday. Put another way, I wanted to find out what was going on, and was thrown when things did not work properly for $\sqrt 7.$

Answer (score 6):

Yes, using the Pell equation is a great idea! In this case, the best Pell equation to use is $x^2-2003y^2 = -2$ (there are no solutions to the $-1$ version of this Pell equation). Given such a solution, note that
$$
xy\sqrt{2003} - x^2 = \frac{2x}{y\sqrt{2003} + x} = \frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+2} + x},
$$
and therefore
$$
0 < xy\sqrt{2003} - x^2 < 1,
$$
showing that $\lfloor xy\sqrt{2003} \rfloor = x^2$.

The first solution to the Pell equation $x^2-2003y^2 = -2$ is $(x,y) = (65912269,1472739)$, and an infinite family of solutions can be generated in the usual way using the fundamental solution $(x_1,y_1) = (4344427204728362,97071569134791)$ to $x^2-2003y^2 = 1$. (And indeed, these two solutions come exactly from the convergents indicated by the red numbers in Jack D'Aurizio's answer!)

Comment: Nice, this gets it done! An uncomfortably large fundamental solution for, say, a contest question :-)

Comment: necessary to be able to solve $x^2 - d y^2 = -2$ or $x^2 - d y^2 = -1.$  I solved $x^2 - 7 y^2 = -3$ and $ \lfloor xy \sqrt 7 \rfloor$ is always one larger than a square.

Comment: in case of interest: I put another CW answer just now, why $x^2 - d y^2 = -k$ does not work for this problem when $k \geq 3.$ Also, I put a question yesterday as to why there seems to be little trouble finding squares anyway. Turns out to be 1916 theorem of Weyl. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937378/when-is-the-floor-of-an-integer-times-the-square-root-of-seven-a-square

Answer (score 3):

Make this CW... the business with $xy \sqrt d$ does not work, as such, for $\sqrt 7.$ However, we seem to have no trouble finding $n$ for which $\lfloor n \sqrt 7 \rfloor$ is a square. So, are there infinitely many of these?

```
     38    100 = 2^2 * 5^2
     46    121 = 11^2
     64    169 = 13^2
     97    256 = 2^8
    167    441 = 3^2 * 7^2
    183    484 = 2^2 * 11^2
    200    529 = 23^2
    218    576 = 2^6 * 3^2
    318    841 = 29^2
    437   1156 = 2^2 * 17^2
    490   1296 = 2^4 * 3^4
    546   1444 = 2^2 * 19^2
    575   1521 = 3^2 * 13^2
    605   1600 = 2^6 * 5^2
    667   1764 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 7^2
    699   1849 = 43^2
    732   1936 = 2^4 * 11^2
    800   2116 = 2^2 * 23^2
    835   2209 = 47^2
    871   2304 = 2^8 * 3^2
    945   2500 = 2^2 * 5^4
   1062   2809 = 53^2
   1316   3481 = 59^2
   1361   3600 = 2^4 * 3^2 * 5^2
   1453   3844 = 2^2 * 31^2
   1597   4225 = 5^2 * 13^2
   1697   4489 = 67^2
   1748   4624 = 2^4 * 17^2
   2070   5476 = 2^2 * 37^2
   2241   5929 = 7^2 * 11^2
   2359   6241 = 79^2
   2419   6400 = 2^8 * 5^2
   2480   6561 = 3^8
   2604   6889 = 83^2
   2667   7056 = 2^4 * 3^2 * 7^2
   2731   7225 = 5^2 * 17^2
   2861   7569 = 3^2 * 29^2
   2927   7744 = 2^6 * 11^2
   2994   7921 = 89^2
   3130   8281 = 7^2 * 13^2
   3340   8836 = 2^2 * 47^2
   3630   9604 = 2^2 * 7^4
   3780  10000 = 2^4 * 5^4
   4010  10609 = 103^2
   4247  11236 = 2^2 * 53^2
   4657  12321 = 3^2 * 37^2
   5086  13456 = 2^4 * 29^2
   5174  13689 = 3^4 * 13^2
   5263  13924 = 2^2 * 59^2
   5443  14400 = 2^6 * 3^2 * 5^2
   5534  14641 = 11^4
   5626  14884 = 2^2 * 61^2
   5906  15625 = 5^6
   6290  16641 = 3^2 * 43^2
   6586  17424 = 2^4 * 3^2 * 11^2
   6686  17689 = 7^2 * 19^2
   6787  17956 = 2^2 * 67^2
   6991  18496 = 2^6 * 17^2
   7198  19044 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 23^2
   7303  19321 = 139^2
   7729  20449 = 11^2 * 13^2
   7947  21025 = 5^2 * 29^2
   8057  21316 = 2^2 * 73^2
   8279  21904 = 2^4 * 37^2
   8618  22801 = 151^2
   8848  23409 = 3^4 * 17^2
   8964  23716 = 2^2 * 7^2 * 11^2
   9676  25600 = 2^10 * 5^2
```

Answer (score 3):

CW again.  Comment on the pretty idea in the other answers: Suppose we have
$$  x^2 - d y^2 = -k, $$
with small integer $k > 0.$
$$  ( x - y \sqrt d) (x + y \sqrt d) = -k, $$
$$ x - y \sqrt d = \frac{-k}{x + y \sqrt d}, $$
$$ x = y \sqrt d - \frac{k}{x + y \sqrt d}, $$
$$ x^2 = xy \sqrt d - \frac{kx}{x + y \sqrt d}, $$
$$  xy \sqrt d = x^2 + \frac{kx}{x + y \sqrt d}. $$
If $kx < x + y \sqrt d,$ then $\lfloor xy \sqrt d \rfloor = x^2.$

When is $kx < x + y \sqrt d ?$ We know $ x - y \sqrt d < 0,$ so that
$y \sqrt d > x.$ That is, 
$$ x + y \sqrt d > 2x.  $$
Therefore, if $k = 1$ or $k = 2,$ we do get $\lfloor xy \sqrt d \rfloor = x^2.$

However, as I found when doing $x^2 - 7 y^2 = -3,$ if $k \geq 3,$ this does not work. Let me prove that, need some more time...

This will do. If $x^2 - d y^2 = -k$ and the very mild $x > \sqrt \frac{k}{3},$ but  $y \sqrt d \geq 2x,$ then $d y^2 \geq 4 x^2.$ Then $x^2 - d y^2 \leq - 3 x^2.$ However, we made the mild bound $x > \sqrt \frac{k}{3},$ so that $3 x^2 > k.$ It follows that $x^2 - d y^2 < k.$ This contradicts the assumption that $y \sqrt d \geq 2x.$ So, except for a small finite number of cases with  $x \leq \sqrt \frac{k}{3},$ we have
$$  y \sqrt d < 2x,  $$
$$ x + y \sqrt d < 3x,  $$
$$ \frac{1}{x + y \sqrt d} > \frac{1}{3x}.  $$ From
$$  xy \sqrt d = x^2 + \frac{kx}{x + y \sqrt d} $$ this says
$$  xy \sqrt d > x^2 + \frac{kx}{3x}, $$
$$  xy \sqrt d > x^2 + \frac{k}{3}. $$
That is, if $k \geq 3,$ unless $x \leq \sqrt \frac{k}{3},$ 
$$ \lfloor xy \sqrt d \rfloor \neq x^2 . $$