# When is the floor of an integer times the square root of seven a square?

Tags: number-theory

This is from [This sequence $\lfloor \sqrt{2003}\cdot n\rfloor $ contains an infinite number of square numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937001/this-sequence-lfloor-sqrt2003-cdot-n-rfloor-contains-an-infinite-number-o)

The business with $\lfloor xy \sqrt d \rfloor$ does not work, as such, for $\sqrt 7,$ as we cannot solve $x^2 - 7 y^2 = -1$ or $x^2 - 7 y^2 = -2.$ We can solve $x^2 - 7 y^2 = -3,$ but that is not good enough for this purpose. However, we seem to have no trouble finding $n$ for which $\lfloor n \sqrt 7 \rfloor$ is a square. So, are there infinitely many of these?

```
     38    100 = 2^2 * 5^2
     46    121 = 11^2
     64    169 = 13^2
     97    256 = 2^8
    167    441 = 3^2 * 7^2
    183    484 = 2^2 * 11^2
    200    529 = 23^2
    218    576 = 2^6 * 3^2
    318    841 = 29^2
    437   1156 = 2^2 * 17^2
    490   1296 = 2^4 * 3^4
    546   1444 = 2^2 * 19^2
    575   1521 = 3^2 * 13^2
    605   1600 = 2^6 * 5^2
    667   1764 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 7^2
    699   1849 = 43^2
    732   1936 = 2^4 * 11^2
    800   2116 = 2^2 * 23^2
    835   2209 = 47^2
    871   2304 = 2^8 * 3^2
    945   2500 = 2^2 * 5^4
   1062   2809 = 53^2
   1316   3481 = 59^2
   1361   3600 = 2^4 * 3^2 * 5^2
   1453   3844 = 2^2 * 31^2
   1597   4225 = 5^2 * 13^2
   1697   4489 = 67^2
   1748   4624 = 2^4 * 17^2
   2070   5476 = 2^2 * 37^2
   2241   5929 = 7^2 * 11^2
   2359   6241 = 79^2
   2419   6400 = 2^8 * 5^2
   2480   6561 = 3^8
   2604   6889 = 83^2
   2667   7056 = 2^4 * 3^2 * 7^2
   2731   7225 = 5^2 * 17^2
   2861   7569 = 3^2 * 29^2
   2927   7744 = 2^6 * 11^2
   2994   7921 = 89^2
   3130   8281 = 7^2 * 13^2
   3340   8836 = 2^2 * 47^2
   3630   9604 = 2^2 * 7^4
   3780  10000 = 2^4 * 5^4
   4010  10609 = 103^2
   4247  11236 = 2^2 * 53^2
   4657  12321 = 3^2 * 37^2
   5086  13456 = 2^4 * 29^2
   5174  13689 = 3^4 * 13^2
   5263  13924 = 2^2 * 59^2
   5443  14400 = 2^6 * 3^2 * 5^2
   5534  14641 = 11^4
   5626  14884 = 2^2 * 61^2
   5906  15625 = 5^6
   6290  16641 = 3^2 * 43^2
   6586  17424 = 2^4 * 3^2 * 11^2
   6686  17689 = 7^2 * 19^2
   6787  17956 = 2^2 * 67^2
   6991  18496 = 2^6 * 17^2
   7198  19044 = 2^2 * 3^2 * 23^2
   7303  19321 = 139^2
   7729  20449 = 11^2 * 13^2
   7947  21025 = 5^2 * 29^2
   8057  21316 = 2^2 * 73^2
   8279  21904 = 2^4 * 37^2
   8618  22801 = 151^2
   8848  23409 = 3^4 * 17^2
   8964  23716 = 2^2 * 7^2 * 11^2
   9676  25600 = 2^10 * 5^2
```

Comment: It's a consequence of one of Weyl's equidistribution theorems that the squares are of the form $\lfloor n \sqrt 7 \rfloor$ "randomly" with probability $1/\sqrt 7$

Comment: @mercio this? "In 1916, Weyl proved that the sequence $a, 2^2a, 3^2a, ... \bmod 1$ is uniformly distributed on the unit interval."

Comment: this one should work, yes.

Answer (score 3):

CW.

From @mercio  in 1916 Weyl showed that, for an irrational $\alpha > 0,$ the values
$$ \alpha, 4 \alpha, 9 \alpha, 16 \alpha, \ldots, k^2 \alpha, \ldots  $$
are uniformly distributed (their fractional parts) in the unit interval. This is Satz 13 on journal page 334 in [WEYL pdf](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/pdfcache/PPN235181684_0077/PPN235181684_0077___LOG_0036.pdf)

if $0 < \delta < 1,$ and $$ \frac{k^2}{\sqrt 7} = n - \delta, $$ then $$  k^2 = n \sqrt 7 - \delta \sqrt 7, $$ or $$ n \sqrt 7 = k^2 + \delta \sqrt 7,$$ and if $\delta \sqrt 7 < 1$ we win. That is, when $0 < \delta < \frac{1}{\sqrt 7}.$